# Adding new rows dynamically to table with loop - android

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow

I am trying to do rss reader for android. I take datas from webservice and put into arraylist. Then i take that arraylist in activity class..I want to create table rows and textviews which count is equal to arraylist size.There are no problems here.But when i execute the application all text views gives same result(last item of arraylist).All arraylist items are different.
I expect that result

> news[1]
>   news[2]
>   news[3] ....

but i get

> news[20]
>   news[20]
>   news[20]

what is wrong with that i dont get it. I try the create textview and row instances out of the for loop but i get ".IllegalStateException:the specified child already has a parent" exception.
I have a news pojo and Here is my code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.guncel);
    WebService ws = new WebService();
    TableLayout tb = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tbl1);

    news news1 = null;
    List<news> newslist;
    URL serviceURL;
    try {
        serviceURL = new URL(
                "http://rss.hurriyet.com.tr/rss.aspx?sectionId=1");
        newslist = ws.getList(serviceURL);
        for (news new1 : newslist) {
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            TextView txtview = new TextView(this);
            row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            news1 = (news) newslist.get(i);
            txtview.setText(new1.getTitle());
            System.out.println(new1.getTitle());
            row.addView(txtview);
            tb.addView(row);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

---

Ok its my fault.. I didnt check carefully my List. All items in list which represents objects, are same. Sorry for bad question.

Answer (score 1):

use this way if you are using foreach loop:

```
 foreach (news new1 : newslist) {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        txtview.setText(new1.getTitle());
        System.out.println(new1.getTitle());
        row.addView(txtview);
        tb.addView(row);
    }
```

and using for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < newslist.size(); i++) {
     TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            news1 = (news) newslist.get(i);
            txtview.setText(new1.getTitle());
            System.out.println(new1.getTitle());
            row.addView(txtview);
            tb.addView(row);
}
```

Comment: Nope i get same result..you delete only "news1 = (news) newslist.get(i);".. and i edit the code part, i create textview in for loop.

Comment: ok System.out.println(new1.getTitle());
 printing same title  or different?

Comment: yeah it gives same results. but i control the webservice.class There are all different list items.